# Excel Formula - Sum Relevant Rows From Fixed Point Until an Indexed Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the linked spreadsheet I am trying to sum all instances of a column R category (for this example lets say "CAM Income") from January until the date in cell B1.

In this case, the sum should be the total of (`B7:F7`) and (`B9:F9`). I can use `sumif` and `sumproduct` to get one column, but I would like for it do all the relevant columns up to the specified date.

Thank you very much for the assistance.

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using an array formula (enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using an array formula by using `=SUMPRODUCT`

**For example:**

[image: Screenshot]

**The formula in `J5` is:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$5:$G$9)*($C$4:$G$4<=$C$2)*($I$5:$I$9=I5))
```